Should I stop using text files as data storage in production?
My question is about system design (and not solving a technical hurdle), but it's nonetheless quite specific.
I currently have an application storing big chunks of data in text files. The context of the application is as follows:

data is naturally divided into chunks (which makes files convenient)
parsing is quite fast (I recall benchmarks of about 400M lines/s single-threaded - lines are quite small, but I find it hard to believe any DB would achieve that)
after storage, subsequent processing is also straightforward: said chunks are processed sequentially, or independent of each other. The data is never modified.

So the advantages of using files are:

no dependence on server software and client libraries
easy archiving, inspection, recovery, repair, processing with command line tools
data writing is trivial (no networking or severed connections involved, DB server versions, maintenance downtime etc.)
everything is faster than using a database, but also in an easier to control way. Instead of managing performance impacts of server options, client options, TCP options, packet size and disk performance you only have to care about read/write size and sequential disk speeds.

The advantages of using an actual database do not seem worth the tradeoffs:

corruption protection: in this application I don't really care if a small part of a particular file is corrupted ; losing a few rows is no big deal, and a bad line of text does not corrupt the rest of the file thanks to redundancy of text formats (using separators and line endings). As for whole-file corruptions (which I've seen happen in other contexts), I have never seen them happen on modern server filesystems, while I have seen unrecoverable database corruptions on the same filesystems (go figure)
easy availability of any data: again this doesn't really apply here, since the nature of the processing is very streamy and naturally divided into chunks ; no caching or random-access is needed
concurrency / scalability: this has never been needed thanks to the streaming nature of writes (everything ends up on a couple of front-end servers which merely queue up incoming data for writing)

Am I missing key advantages of using an actual database? Apart from MariaDB (which I understand to be the fastest at storing and retrieving structured data), are there any other systems that I should have looked at?

You wrote: "everything is faster than using a database". Hard to figure out why anybody else would bother to even invent databases if that statement is true.

I'm not arguig the need for databases, for which there are many good reasons. But there's no denying than using plain files for streaming data (sequential read / write) is faster. It doesn't necessarily make files a good idea.

Nope. Reading uncompressed text files/searching data in specific columns is very unlikely to be faster as compared to say duckdb using parquet/divided parquet data sets. Even writing giant plain text files to NAS  on a loaded network is likely to be slower.

Yes, when I say streaming, I mean that you're processing whole tables sequentially, i.e. not searching. It's a very special use case where caching ends up overwhelmed and databases mostly add overhead. I'll take a look at duckdb.
